# Force PHP Unit to use SOAP Request

Tags: php, soap, phpunit

I am testing a web app that gathers the data from SOAP services. but PHPUnit doesn't call the SOAP services by default instead it encourages you to use Mock Objects.

However I want to test the app using this SOAP service. Is there a way to force PHPUnit to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise against doing this.
Unit tests (an important factor in ensuring the stability of your software) should never be dependent on the availability of web services. And unit tests are meant to run fast which they wouldn't if they used SOAP calls.

If you really want to ensure the availability of a web service, implement some kind of independent service that checks the availability.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use real objects and real data - PHPUnit should happily allow it.

But remember that this completely defeats the purpose of unit testing. When using a SOAP service, you rely on web traffic and server responses that are completely out of your control. Anything can happen there and your tests will eventually fail in such an uncontrolled environment. The point is that your tests are absolutely deterministic: you should know the input data, control the process of its processing and verify the output. If you take the data processing control out, it's not a unit test anymore.